# Arc Hydro logfile location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.7, arc-hydro

I am trying to identify the location of Arc Hydro log file.

Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course this assumes that you are logging geoprocessing operations.  If so, that would depend on what OS you were running.  [See here for more information.](https://C:%5CUsers%5C%3Cuser%20name%3E%5CAppData%5C(Local%20or%20LocalLow%20or%20Roaming)%5CESRI%5CDesktop10.2%5CArcToolbox%5C)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. However, I am not able to follow the link. Would you please check? I am using Windows 10.